# Find a tag in current element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find 2 tags in a web element. I have a list of these elements found by `href` ( contains "http://www.example.com/result=" ).

So I have this:

```
for elem in elements:
    # don't know what to type here
```

I want to get a touple, in this case `('THS','http://www.example.com/result=1'`)

```
<tr bgcolor="FFF4FF">
    <td class="main" align="right">&nbsp;87&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="main" align="center">&nbsp;THS&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="main">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/result=1">xxx
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried to do this:

```
for elem in elements:
    shortcut = elem.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@align="center"]/text()')
    href = elem.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"http://www.example.com")]/@href')
```

But there is a problem that Selenium looks in the whole page source, not just in current element.

Do you know how to look for this tags in current element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to tell Selenium via the "`.`" operator that you want to search from the current element on.

Then you should extract the values via `.text` and `get_attribute("value")`

Just `//` means "search the whole site"

Using `.//` means search from the current element on:

Given that `elements` contains the `tr` elements, your modified code would be:

```
for elem in elements:
    shortcut = elem.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@align="center"]').text
    href = elem.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@href,"http://www.example.com")]').get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. I'm just curious, why did you change getting the text and href. I was trying it the same way before (/text() to get text) and it was returning some exception but I think  that it is a correct syntax. Am I wrong?

Comment: glad to be of help! find_element returns a node-element, and /text() in the xpath does not return this kind of element. furthermore .../@href is not a valid xpath expression and then in Python there is no get_text() method but just the .text to extract text. cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

Try `relative xpath`-

```
href = elem.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@align="center"]).find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@href,"http://www.example.com")]').get_attribute('@href')
```

or `following` axis-

```
href = elem.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@align="center"]/following::a[contains(@href,"http://www.example.com")][1]').get_attribute('@href')
```

or `descendant` axis

```
href = elem.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@align="center"]/descendant::a[contains(@href,"http://www.example.com")][1]').get_attribute('@href')
```